# First Item in woocommerce Loop still showing element

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to remove Woocommerce 'add to cart' button and the product price on a specific product category - which ive got to work... ALMOST!

The first item in the loop is still showing the product price, see screenshot.

[first item shows price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiDsA.jpg)

im not really sure why? Perhaps my hook aren't quite right?

here is my code:

```js
//REMOVE ADD TO CART AND PRICE
//removes add to cart buttons and product price on product of 'muslin' category

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'remove_product_description_add_cart_button' );
function remove_product_description_add_cart_button() { 
    $categories = array('muslins');

    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', get_the_id() ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price',10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart',10);
    }
}
```

Comment: your `add_action` is called `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` which means it runs after the item is shown. Assuming it exists, you should change it to `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title`

Comment: ah, i see - all working now, thanks so much!!